# AWS Load Balancer Health Check Behaviour

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, health-monitoring

I've been working on the reliability of EC2 instances running some Python code to accept TCP connections.

**Set Up:**
The script is set up to accept a number of connections and do some processing and send back results. Pings from the ELB are recognised successfully and the machine becomes healthy.

**Problem:**
If I simulate a deadlock during the processing with an infinite loop, the pings are accepted but the Python server never closes the client; it remains in the loop. The strange thing is, although the machine cannot accept any more connections the instance is labelled as healthy. I would expect the machine to be unhealthy as no more pings can be accepted by it.

I'm wondering if the fact that the instance has accepted pings already and the connections are still open signifies a "healthy" machine? Or if there is something else terrible happening here? And hopefully, how to fix it!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should only remain healthy if the server is returning HTTP 200 to the request. It will also be using HTTP 1.1, retaining an open connection to the server rather than dropping and re-creating it. Remaining healthy indicates the ELB is getting continued 200 responses to ping attempts, from your server.

Are you sure the python script is involved in responding to the ping? What is the ping requesting? I recommend that the health check test an URL which your application actively processes in a similar manner to production requests.

Troubleshooting docs here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-healthcheck.html

Comment: The Python script accepts the connection from the pings and would normally close the connection again, once it realises that it is in fact a ping.

But in the deadlock simulation it accepts the ping and that's it. It doesn't accept any more connections from the load balancer so I'm not sure why the machine is seen as healthy.

Comment: The ELB maintains the connection and sends subsequent requests over that existing connection, the script must be responding with HTTP 200 to the ELB healthcheck. You can test this manually by connecting to your server under the same conditions, using the "nc" tool (on unix/linux) and executing the GET requests that the ELB health check sends.

Comment: But what I don't understand is that if the script is doing nothing (literally a `while True: continue`) then why are the initial requests not timing out?

Comment: Your server is responding with HTTP 200 to the ELB healthcheck. I recommend running tcpdump on the server to confirm the traffic between instance and the ELB.